# Lucene StoredField vs StringField performance

Tags: java, lucene

In lucene indexing part, i started using StoredField, where i dont need to index the fields(before i was using StringField for the same fields).

This is basically for reducing some index space.

I am processing the file with 1 million records, but i dont see any performance difference. But soon i might have to process more than 100 million records.

so, i would like to know will there be any performance hit when i use StoredField compare to StringField?

Thanks
Shankar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your task is I/O-bound rather than CPU-bound as the most time is spent on document merging rather than simplified indexing (which, for `StringField`, is very cheap).

Profiling would likely help to reveal if this guess is incorrect.

Comment: This comment is more helpful.. i will profile once i have the more records.